# Excel Macro VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to vba and excel macros.

I would like to create a command button that asks the user to input if they are searching for a policy or a procedure or a form.  Then ask the user for search words.  The result of the search is to appear as a list on the first worksheet.

The excel spreadsheet has 9 worksheets.  The first worksheet is an introduction with the search feature.  The remaining 8 worksheets contain data with 2 columns.  The first column is the name of the policy, procedure or form.   The second column is the type of document (i.e. policy, procedure or form).  The # of rows for each type of document vary between worksheets so the defined cell range is different for each worksheet for each type of document.

Comment: So what's your question? Nobody is going to write your code for you; however, if you have code and are having trouble with a certain element people would be more inclined to help.

Comment: There are many good excel vba tutorials out there.  With a few hours of study you can probably pick up the basics and get more guidance here.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume that you, like many people, are confused on how to even start, and not that you are trying to use this site as a free Macro Repository.

With that in mind, I'm going to give you the links and tools to do this for yourself. I will discuss the type of VBA that I would use to solve this so that you have the terms available to look up.

First and foremost, you need a command button. The easiest way to get this is to use the Developer tab on the ribbon. You can learn about that [here](http://www.addintools.com/documents/excel/how-to-add-developer-tab.html). Once you get the button, you'll need to assign a macro to it. More info on that [here](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Add-a-button-and-assign-a-macro-to-it-in-a-worksheet-adec9584-3925-47c9-998f-def71ff6a4a3). I would suggest the Form Control button as it is a bit easier and can handle your task fine.

Before you can assign the macro, though, you need to build the macro. [Excel-Easy](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/create-a-macro.html) will show you how to get to the VBA editor through the GUI, or you could press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>.

First, you will want an input box. The information on that can be found at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/Ff839468.aspx). That article also has some examples to get that running.

You'll want to assign the input to a variable like these at [OzGrid](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/variables.htm). Based on your description, I'd say you want a [string](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/variables.html#string).

Now, you'll want a `For Each...Next` [loop](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/for-each-loop.htm). Something like this:

```
For Each Worksheet in ThisWorkBook.Worksheets
    'more code here
Next Worksheet
```

For that, you'll want to learn about [Worksheet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/Ff194464(v=office.14).aspx), [ThisWorkBook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193227(v=office.14).aspx), and [Worksheets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821537(v=office.14).aspx).

Inside of that loop, you'll need to find the last row of each worksheet. This is a very common thing to do when working with Excel and can be found many places, such as [The Spreadsheet Guru](http://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/7/7/5-different-ways-to-find-the-last-row-or-last-column-using-vba). Once you've done that, you'll want to define a range using the last row. That last link should help you there, too.

Once you've got your range, it's time to use the [Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746(v=office.14).aspx) method. The first example on that page is what you're going to do. You'll just be using that variable we set the input to earlier instead of the number 2, and you won't need to replace it. That uses a `With` [statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx), an `If` [statement (article at Tech On The Net)](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/if_then.php), a `Do While` [loop](http://www.excelfunctions.net/VBA-Loops.html#DoWhileLoop), and the `Not` [operator](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/not.php).

Now, each time that you find it, you want to move it. To make sure you don't just paste all the relevant info over each other, you'll want to set a last row for your first page now. Then you can use the `Value` [property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195193.aspx) to quickly and easily move the data from where it is to the first sheet. Be sure to add 1 to the last row when you transfer the value or it will always just transfer it to the last row instead of the next row beneath it.

Good Luck!

NOTE: I specifically mentioned some of the sites that I got these links from. These are pretty good references. For more references, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/excel/info). Also, [Google](https://www.google.com/) is your friend ;). If you have a particularly hard time with any section of this, you can always post it as a new question for that specific problem.

Comment: Nice set of breadcrumbs for someone starting out. I'd recommend the Worksheets collection instead of Sheets, however. Sheets includes chart sheets, which could really confuse a new VBA coder. The Worksheets collection, on the other hand, is purely worksheets.

Comment: @ExcelHero Good point. I've edited the post to have the Worksheets collection instead of the Sheets collection.

Comment: Used Advanced Filter to create a filter on a separate wksht in same workbook. Within the list range are cells that have hyperlinks. The advanced filter is on Wksht 1, brings all of Row 1, Row 2, etc to wksht. In Title column is the word without a hyperlink attached to it.  How do I bring hyperlink onto Wksht 2 along with all of other info.

Macros below: 

Sub Filterme()

Filterme Macro
'
'
        Sheet10.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
        CriteriaRange:=Range("FilterData!Criteria"), CopyToRange:=Range( _
        "FilterData!Extract"), Unique:=False

Comment: @Deepa Glad to see you're making progress! That would actually be easier for people to find if you posted it as a new question. Once you do that, a bunch of people will be able to see it and offer help.

Answer (score -1):

The following is the answer. Just trying to learn VBA

```
Sub consolidate()
Dim x As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim m As Integer

 x = InputBox("enter form/procedure/process", "enter type", "form")
 'take input string as variable

m = 1
 'this variable  to increment number o row
 For Each Worksheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
   'iterate through all worksheets

   k = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))
   'k is to find last row

   For j = 1 To k
     'iterate through all rows

    If Range("b" & j).Value = x Then
        Range("A" & j & ":" & "B" & j).Copy
       ' copy the rows
       Worksheets("result").Range("A" & m & ":" & "B" & m).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    'paste the rows
    m = m + 1
End If
Next j
Worksheet.Activate
Debug.Print Worksheet.Name
```

Next Worksheet

End Sub

Answer (score -1):

```
Sub scrape_image_links()
Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim X As Integer
Dim Y As Integer
Dim rowIndex As Integer
Dim colIndex As Integer
Dim linkName As String
Dim url As String
Dim compName As String
Dim pageUrl As String
Dim flag As Boolean
Dim altFlag As Boolean
Dim attributeFlag As Boolean
Dim picIteratorFlag As String
Dim catnavIteratorFlag As String
Dim a

Dim checkMediaWidth As Integer

Dim iterator As Object
Dim lnkIterator As Object

Dim picIterator As Object
Dim catnavIterator As Object

Dim webpage As HTMLDocument

rowIndex = 5
colIndex = 5

pageUrl = Sheets("input page").Range("b5").Text
Set ie = New InternetExplorerMedium
'ie.Visible = True 'Optional if you want to make the window visible
ie.navigate pageUrl

Do While ie.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until ie.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
While ie.Busy
    DoEvents
Wend
'Range("J17:V").Delete Shift:=xlUp'

Set DivElement = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("div")
flag = False

Sheets("output page").Select
    Cells.Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Range("a1").Select

For Each iterator In DivElement
    flag = False
    picIteratorFlag = False
    catnavIteratorFlag = False
    If iterator.hasAttribute("data-component") Then
        Set LnkElement = iterator.getElementsByTagName("a")
            For Each lnkIterator In LnkElement
            attributeFlag = False
            attributeFlag = lnkIterator.hasAttribute("data-lnk")

                If attributeFlag = True Then
                    compName = iterator.getAttribute("data-component")
                    linkName = lnkIterator.getAttribute("data-lnk")

                    Set PicElement = lnkIterator.getElementsByTagName("source")
                    Set catnavElement = lnkIterator.getElementsByTagName("img")

                        For Each picIterator In PicElement
                            If picIterator.hasAttribute("media") Then
                                checkMediaWidth = StrComp(picIterator.getAttribute("media"), "(min-width: 0px)")
                                If checkMediaWidth = 0 Then
                                url = picIterator.getAttribute("srcset")
                                Call ImageOnly(rowIndex, colIndex, compName, linkName, url)
                                flag = True
                                colInc colIndex
                                End If
                            End If
                        Next picIterator

                End If
            Next lnkIterator
            If flag = True Then
            rowInc rowIndex
            End If
            resetCollInc colIndex
    End If

Next iterator

ie.Quit
Set ie = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Try adding some description to your comments :)